Convert txt file to excel file with headers in Matlab
I'm struggling on splitting a txt file made of 1 column of N blocks made of 1000 rows. The first 3 rows of each block is an header, followed by 1000 rows of data. Row 1001 will be the next block starting with the three headers in this way:
#Header1
#Header2_1,Header2_2
#Header3
Data1_1-Data1_2
...
Data1000_1-Data1001_2
Header1
Header2
Header3
Data1002_1-Data1002_2
...
Data2003_1-Data2003_2
:::

Each row of data is made of two sets, so I'd like to split into two columns the data, keeping each header in this way
         Block1           |           Block2             |       Block3 ... 
Header1                   | Header1
Header2 1_1 | Header2 1_2 | Header2 2_1 | Header2 2_2
Header3                   | Header3
Data1_1 | Data1_2         | Data1002_1 | Data1002_2
...                       | ...
Data1001_1 | Data1001_2   | Data2003_1 | Data2003_2

I tried with reshape but without success:
filename = 'text.txt';
data = splitlines(filename);
NRows = 1001;
NumBlocks = length(data)/NRows
Data_Reshaped = reshape(data,NRows,NumBlocks);

but it works partially, because I obtain a 1001 x 12 cell array and each cell has
Data1_1-Data1_2

with the - as delimiter. How can I split again this cell into two columns in ordered way and get a 1001x24 cell arrays?
Than the result should be exported in excel but I guess writetable function should do the job.

The example I put in the post is not sufficient? I used | to show what columns should be separated

What about removing Header1 and Header3 (I can delete them easily because almost useless) and keep just Header2 that has the same format of all rows? In case, I will edit the question

I've answered now, so if editing the question invalidates the answer it's probably easier not to edit anything, unless it doesn't give you a solution and the edits are still required

That's perfect! It's doing the job perfectly!

You need to do three things to make your data flat/uniform enough to put into Excel

Split the single-header rows into two headers, the 2nd of which is just an empty string but you need two columns so you can stack with others properly

Split the two-header row into two headers, using , as the delimiter

Split the data rows into two, using - as the delimiter


I've created an example (at the bottom of this answer) with 3 data rows for testing:
First, read in the data
% Use fileread to get the entire file contents, split on newlines
dat = fileread( 'text.txt' );
dat = splitlines( dat );

% Define the schema for this data: 3 header rows then 3 data rows
nHeaders = 3;
nDataRows = 3;
nPerBlock = nHeaders + nDataRows;

% Do an initial reshape to get each "block" into its own column of the cell
dat = reshape( dat, nPerBlock, [] );

Now we can do the numbered operations above to get a cell array with two-columns per cell:
% Split single-item headers from 'Header1' into {'Header1',''}
dat([1,3],:) = cellfun( @(x) {x,''}, dat([1,3],:), 'uni', 0 );

% Split two-item headers from 'Header2 2_1,Header2 2_2' into {'Header2 2_1','Header2 2_2'}
dat(2,:) = cellfun( @(x) strsplit( x, ',' ), dat(2,:), 'uni', 0 );

% Split the data from 'Data1_1-Data1_2' into {'Data1_1','Data1_2'}
dat(nHeaders+1:end,:) = cellfun( @(x) strsplit( x, '-' ), dat(nHeaders+1:end,:), 'uni', 0 );

Now you need to do a final bit of restructuring to expand and flatten the cell array:
dat = arrayfun( @(r) [dat{r,:}], 1:size(dat,1), 'uni', 0 );
dat = vertcat( dat{:} );

Final output:

Since your data is a cell array rather than a table at this point (despite looking a bit like a table), you probably want to use writecell() to write into Excel or a csv.

Example data text.txt:
#Header1
#Header2 1_1,Header2 1_2
#Header3
Data1_1-Data1_2
Data2_1-Data2_2
Data3_1-Data3_2
#Header1
#Header2 2_1,Header2 2_2
#Header3
Data4_1-Data4_2
Data5_1-Data5_2
Data6_1-Data6_2
#Header1
#Header2 3_1,Header2 3_2
#Header3
Data7_1-Data7_2
Data8_1-Data8_2
Data9_1-Data9_2


Could you show me how to use str2double to convert from the fourth row to the end? I saw writing in Excel it takes data as text
